# express js, req.body with bodyParser empty or undefined

Tags: forms, express, get, request

I am try to GET data from api in expressJs. I am using 'request'. I would to send the request through a form where the user could choose the title of the film to look for. I do not understand why the req.body.title is empty. I tried also with req.params.title but is not working

Thanks for any help

this is the search.ejs file

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form action="/search" method="GET">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="">Keyword to search</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Harry Potter" name="lang">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="">Keyword to search</label>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="e.g. Harry Potter" name="title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <p>title</p>
        <p> <% film.forEach((singleMovie) => { %>
            <p> <%= singleMovie.title %></p>
        <% }) %> </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is the app.js

I would like to pass the value of the input text field with name title to the variable filmName, after that the user will be redirected to the same page with the search results in the right part of the page

```
    //APP VARIABLES AND IMPORTING
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var request = require('request');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/film_database', {useMongoClient: true});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

//BASIC ROUTE
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index');
});

app.get('/search', (req, res) => {
    var filmName = req.body.title; => this should return the input text
    console.log(filmName);
    var baseAPIAddress = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3"
    var searchAPI= "/search/movie?api_key={my_api_key}&language=fr&query=" + filmName + "&include_adult=false"
    var searchRequest = baseAPIAddress + searchAPI;
    var film = {};

    request(searchRequest, (err, resp, body) => {
         if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
            var film = JSON.parse(body);
            var titleArray = film['results']
            res.redirect('search', {film: titleArray});
        } else {
            console.log('err is: ' + err);
        }
    });

});

//GET => index.js => /search

///SERVER
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('SERVER IS RUNNING AT LOCALHOST://3000');
d});
```

I don't know why I can't get the input value, i tried different ways but is not working. I think GET is correct as I do not want to modify any data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using GET. 
Try **var filmName = req.query.title;**

Comment: Sure sry I tought I did :p